# pandas to_sql method not working when writing data from csv file

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, csv, sqlalchemy

I have a Postgres table built with:

```
create table titanic (
    PassengerId SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    Survived SMALLINT,
    Pclass SMALLINT,
    Name VARCHAR(82),
    Sex VARCHAR(10),
    Age REAL,
    SibSp SMALLINT,
    Parch SMALLINT,
    Ticket VARCHAR(50),
    Fare REAL,
    Cabin VARCHAR(20),
    Embarked VARCHAR(1)
)
```

It is empty in my database:

```
postgres=# select * from titanic;
 passengerid | survived | pclass | name | sex | age | sibsp | parch | ticket | fare | cabin | embarked 
-------------+----------+--------+------+-----+-----+-------+-------+--------+------+-------+----------
(0 rows)
```

Now I am writing a python code that takes the data from csv file and writes into the table, the csv looks like that:

```
     Survived  Pclass                                               Name     Sex   Age  SibSp  Parch            Ticket     Fare Cabin Embarked
0           0       3                            Braund, Mr. Owen Harris    male  22.0      1      0         A/5 21171   7.2500   NaN        S
1           1       1  Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Th...  female  38.0      1      0          PC 17599  71.2833   C85        C
2           1       3                             Heikkinen, Miss. Laina  female  26.0      0      0  STON/O2. 3101282   7.9250   NaN        S
3           1       1       Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)  female  35.0      1      0            113803  53.1000  C123        S
4           0       3                           Allen, Mr. William Henry    male  35.0      0      0            373450   8.0500   NaN        S
..        ...     ...                                                ...     ...   ...    ...    ...               ...      ...   ...      ...
886         0       2                              Montvila, Rev. Juozas    male  27.0      0      0            211536  13.0000   NaN        S
887         1       1                       Graham, Miss. Margaret Edith  female  19.0      0      0            112053  30.0000   B42        S
888         0       3           Johnston, Miss. Catherine Helen "Carrie"  female   NaN      1      2        W./C. 6607  23.4500   NaN        S
889         1       1                              Behr, Mr. Karl Howell    male  26.0      0      0            111369  30.0000  C148        C
890         0       3                                Dooley, Mr. Patrick    male  32.0      0      0            370376   7.7500   NaN        Q
```

And here the code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

connection_uri = "postgresql://postgres:pass@localhost:5432/postgres"
db_engine = create_engine(connection_uri)

def extract_table_to_pandas(tablename,db_engine):
    query = F"SELECT * FROM {tablename}"
    return pd.read_sql(query,db_engine)


df = pd.read_csv('train.csv',sep=',',header=None,skiprows=1,usecols=range(1,12))

df.to_sql("titanic",db_engine,if_exists='append',index=False)
```

However I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1782, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_executemany(
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py", line 951, in do_executemany
    context._psycopg2_fetched_rows = xtras.execute_values(
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/extras.py", line 1270, in execute_values
    cur.execute(b''.join(parts))
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "1" of relation "titanic" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO titanic ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8",...
                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/postgres/connect.py", line 15, in <module>
    df.to_sql("titanic",db_engine,if_exists='append',index=False)
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2872, in to_sql
    sql.to_sql(
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 717, in to_sql
    pandas_sql.to_sql(
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1761, in to_sql
    sql_engine.insert_records(
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1350, in insert_records
    raise err
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1340, in insert_records
    table.insert(chunksize=chunksize, method=method)
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 967, in insert
    exec_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 882, in _execute_insert
    conn.execute(self.table.insert(), data)
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1289, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params, _EMPTY_EXECUTION_OPTS)
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 325, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1481, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1845, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2026, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1782, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_executemany(
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py", line 951, in do_executemany
    context._psycopg2_fetched_rows = xtras.execute_values(
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/extras.py", line 1270, in execute_values
    cur.execute(b''.join(parts))
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column "1" of relation "titanic" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO titanic ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8",...
                             ^

[SQL: INSERT INTO titanic ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11") VALUES (%(1)s, %(2)s, %(3)s, %(4)s, %(5)s, %(6)s, %(7)s, %(8)s, %(9)s, %(10)s, %(11)s)]
[parameters: ({'1': 0, '2': 3, '3': 'Braund, Mr. Owen Harris', '4': 'male', '5': 22.0, '6': 1, '7': 0, '8': 'A/5 21171', '9': 7.25, '10': None, '11': 'S'}, {'1': 1, '2': 1, '3': 'Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)', '4': 'female', '5': 38.0, '6': 1, '7': 0, '8': 'PC 17599', '9': 71.2833, '10': 'C85', '11': 'C'}, {'1': 1, '2': 3, '3': 'Heikkinen, Miss. Laina', '4': 'female', '5': 26.0, '6': 0, '7': 0, '8': 'STON/O2. 3101282', '9': 7.925, '10': None, '11': 'S'}, {'1': 1, '2': 1, '3': 'Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)', '4': 'female', '5': 35.0, '6': 1, '7': 0, '8': '113803', '9': 53.1, '10': 'C123', '11': 'S'}, {'1': 0, '2': 3, '3': 'Allen, Mr. William Henry', '4': 'male', '5': 35.0, '6': 0, '7': 0, '8': '373450', '9': 8.05, '10': None, '11': 'S'}, {'1': 0, '2': 3, '3': 'Moran, Mr. James', '4': 'male', '5': None, '6': 0, '7': 0, '8': '330877', '9': 8.4583, '10': None, '11': 'Q'}, {'1': 0, '2': 1, '3': 'McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J', '4': 'male', '5': 54.0, '6': 0, '7': 0, '8': '17463', '9': 51.8625, '10': 'E46', '11': 'S'}, {'1': 0, '2': 3, '3': 'Palsson, Master. Gosta Leonard', '4': 'male', '5': 2.0, '6': 3, '7': 1, '8': '349909', '9': 21.075, '10': None, '11': 'S'}  ... displaying 10 of 891 total bound parameter sets ...  {'1': 1, '2': 1, '3': 'Behr, Mr. Karl Howell', '4': 'male', '5': 26.0, '6': 0, '7': 0, '8': '111369', '9': 30.0, '10': 'C148', '11': 'C'}, {'1': 0, '2': 3, '3': 'Dooley, Mr. Patrick', '4': 'male', '5': 32.0, '6': 0, '7': 0, '8': '370376', '9': 7.75, '10': None, '11': 'Q'})]
```

From what i understand from this error pandas is still trying to write the column values into the table, even though removed when reading the csv file. I have also tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv('train.csv',sep=',',usecols=range(1,12))

df.to_sql("titanic",db_engine,if_exists='append',index=False)
```

But that doesn't work either, Note that I am skipping the first column since this is defined in the db table as a serial primary key, so postgres should auto increment that by default in my understanding.

This is the result of the second call:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1782, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_executemany(
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py", line 951, in do_executemany
    context._psycopg2_fetched_rows = xtras.execute_values(
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/extras.py", line 1270, in execute_values
    cur.execute(b''.join(parts))
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "Survived" of relation "titanic" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO titanic ("Survived", "Pclass", "Name", "Sex", "A...
                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/postgres/connect.py", line 15, in <module>
    df.to_sql("titanic",db_engine,if_exists='append',index=False)
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2872, in to_sql
    sql.to_sql(
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 717, in to_sql
    pandas_sql.to_sql(
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1761, in to_sql
    sql_engine.insert_records(
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1350, in insert_records
    raise err
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1340, in insert_records
    table.insert(chunksize=chunksize, method=method)
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 967, in insert
    exec_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 882, in _execute_insert
    conn.execute(self.table.insert(), data)
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1289, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params, _EMPTY_EXECUTION_OPTS)
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 325, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1481, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1845, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2026, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1782, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_executemany(
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py", line 951, in do_executemany
    context._psycopg2_fetched_rows = xtras.execute_values(
  File "/root/postgres/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/extras.py", line 1270, in execute_values
    cur.execute(b''.join(parts))
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column "Survived" of relation "titanic" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO titanic ("Survived", "Pclass", "Name", "Sex", "A...
                             ^

[SQL: INSERT INTO titanic ("Survived", "Pclass", "Name", "Sex", "Age", "SibSp", "Parch", "Ticket", "Fare", "Cabin", "Embarked") VALUES (%(Survived)s, %(Pclass)s, %(Name)s, %(Sex)s, %(Age)s, %(SibSp)s, %(Parch)s, %(Ticket)s, %(Fare)s, %(Cabin)s, %(Embarked)s)]
[parameters: ({'Survived': 0, 'Pclass': 3, 'Name': 'Braund, Mr. Owen Harris', 'Sex': 'male', 'Age': 22.0, 'SibSp': 1, 'Parch': 0, 'Ticket': 'A/5 21171', 'Fare': 7.25, 'Cabin': None, 'Embarked': 'S'}, {'Survived': 1, 'Pclass': 1, 'Name': 'Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)', 'Sex': 'female', 'Age': 38.0, 'SibSp': 1, 'Parch': 0, 'Ticket': 'PC 17599', 'Fare': 71.2833, 'Cabin': 'C85', 'Embarked': 'C'}, {'Survived': 1, 'Pclass': 3, 'Name': 'Heikkinen, Miss. Laina', 'Sex': 'female', 'Age': 26.0, 'SibSp': 0, 'Parch': 0, 'Ticket': 'STON/O2. 3101282', 'Fare': 7.925, 'Cabin': None, 'Embarked': 'S'}, {'Survived': 1, 'Pclass': 1, 'Name': 'Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)', 'Sex': 'female', 'Age': 35.0, 'SibSp': 1, 'Parch': 0, 'Ticket': '113803', 'Fare': 53.1, 'Cabin': 'C123', 'Embarked': 'S'}, {'Survived': 0, 'Pclass': 3, 'Name': 'Allen, Mr. William Henry', 'Sex': 'male', 'Age': 35.0, 'SibSp': 0, 'Parch': 0, 'Ticket': '373450', 'Fare': 8.05, 'Cabin': None, 'Embarked': 'S'}, {'Survived': 0, 'Pclass': 3, 'Name': 'Moran, Mr. James', 'Sex': 'male', 'Age': None, 'SibSp': 0, 'Parch': 0, 'Ticket': '330877', 'Fare': 8.4583, 'Cabin': None, 'Embarked': 'Q'}, {'Survived': 0, 'Pclass': 1, 'Name': 'McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J', 'Sex': 'male', 'Age': 54.0, 'SibSp': 0, 'Parch': 0, 'Ticket': '17463', 'Fare': 51.8625, 'Cabin': 'E46', 'Embarked': 'S'}, {'Survived': 0, 'Pclass': 3, 'Name': 'Palsson, Master. Gosta Leonard', 'Sex': 'male', 'Age': 2.0, 'SibSp': 3, 'Parch': 1, 'Ticket': '349909', 'Fare': 21.075, 'Cabin': None, 'Embarked': 'S'}  ... displaying 10 of 891 total bound parameter sets ...  {'Survived': 1, 'Pclass': 1, 'Name': 'Behr, Mr. Karl Howell', 'Sex': 'male', 'Age': 26.0, 'SibSp': 0, 'Parch': 0, 'Ticket': '111369', 'Fare': 30.0, 'Cabin': 'C148', 'Embarked': 'C'}, {'Survived': 0, 'Pclass': 3, 'Name': 'Dooley, Mr. Patrick', 'Sex': 'male', 'Age': 32.0, 'SibSp': 0, 'Parch': 0, 'Ticket': '370376', 'Fare': 7.75, 'Cabin': None, 'Embarked': 'Q'})]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
```

The error is an undefined column, which I honestly don't understand why.

Comment: 1) Why is a CSV file about the Titanic called `train.csv`? 2) Why not use the Python [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module directly?

Comment: `print(df)` gives me      `Survived  Pclass                                               Name     Sex   Age  SibSp  Parch            Ticket     Fare Cabin Embarked` when reading `df = pd.read_csv('train.csv',sep=',',usecols=range(1,12))`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver because it comes from kaggle, the filename does not matter anyway, only the content matters.

Comment: @moth - Please [edit] your question to include that additional information.

Comment: What does df.columns return after you read from csv?

Comment: @ScottBoston `Index(['Survived', 'Pclass', 'Name', 'Sex', 'Age', 'SibSp', 'Parch', 'Ticket',
       'Fare', 'Cabin', 'Embarked'],
      dtype='object')`

Comment: Note that column names are case-sensitive in PostgreSQL, so if the table contains a column named "survived" then `INSERT INTO titanic ("Survived", …` wont work.

Comment: oh yes `df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()` and then running again worked. But my create table statement has the uppercase in the first letter, does postgres transform column tables in lowercase always ?

Comment: if you note the `create table` in the question is uppercase however the `select * from titanic` displays lowercase and in fact postgres is taking the uppercase and transforming into lowercase. damnnn

Comment: I need to quote the identifiers to retain their natural case when creating the table I believe.

Comment: Read the docs [Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this.

```
create table titanic (
    "PassengerId" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "Survived" SMALLINT,
    "Pclass" SMALLINT,
    "Name" VARCHAR(82),
    "Sex" VARCHAR(10),
    "Age" REAL,
    "SibSp" SMALLINT,
    "Parch" SMALLINT,
    "Ticket" VARCHAR(50),
    "Fare" REAL,
    "Cabin" VARCHAR(20),
    "Embarked" VARCHAR(1)
);

import psycopg2

con = psycopg2.connect(dbname='test', host='localhost', user='postgres', port=5432)
cur = con.cursor()

with open('train.csv') as csv_file:
    cur.copy_expert('COPY titanic FROM STDIN WITH CSV HEADER', csv_file)
    con.commit()

select count(*) from titanic ;
 count 
-------
   891

wc -l train.csv 
892 train.csv
--Subtract 1 for the header and you get 891.
```

The column names don't really need to be double quoted for this case as the `COPY` will match left to right regardless of column names. Just did it to show how to preserve case. `COPY` is also a much faster way to bulk load a table then `INSERT`s. The caveat is that the `COPY` operation is all or none, a single error will rollback the whole thing.

**FYI**, the `"PassengerId" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY` will cause you issues if you plan on adding rows to this table:

```
 select max("PassengerId") from titanic ;
 max 
-----
 891

--Current value for the sequence behind the serial type.
select * from "titanic_PassengerId_seq";
 last_value | log_cnt | is_called 
------------+---------+-----------
          1 |       0 | f
```

If you enter new rows they will start with a `"PassengerId"` of 1 which will create a duplicate`Primary Key` conflict with the existing rows. You will need to bump the sequence:

```
alter sequence "titanic_PassengerId_seq" restart 892;

 select * from "titanic_PassengerId_seq"
test-*# ;
 last_value | log_cnt | is_called 
------------+---------+-----------
        892 |       0 | f
```

Comment: I believe you need to bump the sequence for the first column because you're copying it right? If you just ignore and leave it default for the first column and copy the rest isn't the auto increment going to roll the sequence and stop at 891?

Comment: It is more work to remove the first column from the CSV file and then specify  the remaining columns in the `COPY`, then to  do it this way and bump the sequence after the import.